# Django 2.0 reusable apps - TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/

Tags: django, templates

Python 3, Django 2.0

I just got to the end of the official Django tutorial, and I'm working on the advanced portion - "How to write reusable apps"

It seems like I was at least partially successful, I can access the Questions and Choices through the admin interface, but when I try to display the http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ I get this error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/

I get a similar error for trying to access a detail page, at http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/

I looked through all the troubleshooting questions I could, and my main question is - how can you access templates that are packaged into an app? The thing I see going wrong is that Django is trying to find the app templates inside the main project directories(ie: /tutorial/templates/polls/detail.html), but they should be "inside" the module I imported from pip.

Are you actually supposed to package the templates into apps this way?  I tried throwing the template files back into tutorial/templates/polls/ and it works just fine, but this goes against what I think should be "reuseability" because then the packaged app won't have it's own templates.

The answers I was able to find seem to be more for older versions of Django, and used a TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting...  Anyone know if there is a way to set that in Django 2?

Directory structure:

```
django-polls/
  LICENSE
  manifest.in
  README.rst
  setup.py
  /dist
  /docs
  /polls
    admin.py
    apps.pyo
    __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    /build
    /migrations
    /static
      /polls
        /images
      style.css
    /templates
      /polls
        detail.html
        index.html
        results.html
```

The project structure is like this:

```
tutorial/
  /mysite  (settings.py, etc)
  /templates
    /admin
      base_site.html
      index.html
  /venv (my virtualenv directory)
  db.sqlite3
  manage.py
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*e7@6=f$r(cu_p@7#*s+6t9r^ouio$x&06s61-0u(n1mo370c6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'polls',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'polls')],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Please include the list of directories that Django searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was case: the file had been named `manifest.in`, when it needed to be capitalized as `MANIFEST.in`. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

Remember to include your `templates` directory in your `MANIFEST.in` file. See step 6 of [packaging your app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app) for more info.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is required, but also pay attention to the case. I've always seen the file cased as `MANIFEST.in`. The OP has it in his tree as `manifest.in`, all lowercase.

Comment: Wow, you got it, thanks so much! I had packaged the templates directory in the manifest, but it was the lowercase issue.

Comment: Great spot @FlipperPA